# Python - beautifulsoup changes attribute positioning

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Hi I am trying to parse html code
I am attaching a few line of html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fontawesome-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/xsIcon.css">
```

When I load this into beautifulsoup it changes attributes position in alphabetic order like code below

```
<link href="assets/css/fontawesome-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="assets/css/xsIcon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

You can see difference initially rel was before href after just loading and write file again order of attributes changes.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening.
Thanks

Comment: Interesting - never noticed. But why do you care?

Comment: My client says it is important for SEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters), you can use custom `HTMLFormatter`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter


txt = '''<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fontawesome-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/xsIcon.css">'''

class UnsortedAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
            yield k, v

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

#before HTMLFormatter
print( soup )

print('-' * 80)

#after HTMLFormatter
print( soup.encode(formatter=UnsortedAttributes()).decode('utf-8') )
```

Prints:

```
<link href="assets/css/fontawesome-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="assets/css/xsIcon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fontawesome-min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/xsIcon.css"/>
```